# ASP.NET MVC 4: Query returning same result if not null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my loop I am searching through each player and checking if they have a stat for today. After the loop, in my list of stats, for each player that did not return null, has same results.

```
      List<Player> Roster = new List<Player>();
        List<Stat> Stats = new List<Stat>();

        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;


        foreach (Roster playerID in PlayerIDS)
        {
            Player player = new Player();
            player = player.GetPlayerByID(playerID.PlayerID);
            Roster.Add(player);

            //Grab stats
            Stat stat = new Stat();
            stat = db.Stats.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Stats WHERE PlayerID=" + player.ID + " AND DATEPART(DAY, Date)=" + today.Day + "AND DATEPART(MONTH, Date)=" + today.Month).SingleOrDefault();

            Stats.Add(stat);


        }

        ViewBag.Roster = Roster;
        ViewBag.Stats = Stats;


        }
```

For each iteration:
playerID = { 3007, 3080, 3103, 3929 , 4614}

I expect stats for 3007, 3929, 4614 and the rest null.

Result:

3007 returns correct stat line

3080 null

3103 null

3929 same stat line as 3007

4614 same stat line as 3007

Comment: You shouldn't hit the db in a `for` loop when you dont need to. You should be using a `SELECT - WHERE IN` clause. You can then use `string.join` to put all the playerid's into your query: `"SELECT * FROM dbo.Stats WHERE PlayerID IN (" + string.Join(",", PlayerIDS.Select(s=>s.ID.ToString())) + "...`

Comment: I have changed it to: Stats = db.Stats.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Stats WHERE PlayerID IN (" + string.Join(",", PlayerIDS.Select(s => s.ID.ToString() ) ) + " AND DATEPART(DAY, Date)=" + today.Day + "AND DATEPART(MONTH, Date)=" + today.Month).ToList();

Comment: I am getting error: Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.

Comment: you forgot the closing bracket before AND

Comment: You SQL Statement has two major problem.  First it definitely allows [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), but I can't tell if users have access (lack of code).  Your query also is Non-[Sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), so it will be slow.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using EF there. Assuming you have a model defined for Stats, you could use LINQ to define the query in strongly typed C# instead. That's probably not related to your issue, but having the compiler sanity check your query does sometimes help you identify overlooked issues.

Something like this, assuming there are no stats beyond the current day.

```
var stat = (from stat in db.Stats
            where stat.PlayerID == playerId &&
            stat.Date > DateTime.Today).SingleOrDefault();
```

Also, do you have an EF model for the Player? I think it would be more reliable and quicker if you could use a foreign key relation to check to see if `Player.Stats.Where(s => s.Date > DateTime.Today)` is null instead of working backwards by querying for the foreign key in `Stats` itself.